# Order by some row matching a specific condition, and then another condition for the rest?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am developing a collaborative writing website called Fablelane, where people can create stories. Now, the system (when people create stories) detects the language of the story, and saves that in the database.

On the front page (http://fablelane.com), there are 3 "Noteworthy stories". Right now, it just picks the 3 highest voted stories, with a simple `ORDER BY` clause.

But if there's a story that's written in the user's language (let's just say that's Danish - `da_DK`), then I want the first of those 3 stories to be the one that matches the language of the user, and the rest of the 2 in English.

So in other words:

- Get the highest voted story that's written in the user's language.

  - If it exists, display that as the first story.
- Then get the 3 (or 2 if the highest voted story matching the language was found) highest voted stories written in English, and display those.

Does that make sense? If not, here's a few use cases.

**Use case 1: A Danish user visiting the site, but where there are no Danish stories**

- Noteworthy story #1: The highest voted story written in English.
- Noteworthy story #2: The second highest voted story written in English.
- Noteworthy story #3: The third highest voted story written in English.

**Use case 2: A Danish user visiting the site, where there's at least one Danish story available**

- Noteworthy story #1: The highest voted story written in Danish.
- Noteworthy story #2: The highest voted story written in English.
- Noteworthy story #3: The second highest voted story written in English.

**Use case 3: An English user visiting the site**

This is exactly the same as *Use case 1*.

---

**Edit 1**

Let's just say (to make it easier) that each story's language is stored in a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column called `Language`, and that the story's table is called `Story`.

The way I fetch the user's language is through the `Request.UserLanguages` property in ASP .NET MVC. In other words, it's a string. To make it easier in the example, let's assume that it matches perfectly with the values in the `Language` column of the `Story`.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the query that generates the stories, how you are representing the language of each story, and how you know the users language?

Comment: Yup - I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing anything about your schema... I think one way to accomplish this might be to produce two result sets and union them and get the top 3 from that. It might not be the best way though and I'm sure the query can be written better (and probably with better performance).

Something like this maybe:

```
// first some sample data
declare @stories table (story varchar(20), lang char(2), votes int)
insert @stories values 
('Story 1', 'DK', 1),('Story 2', 'DK', 3),
('Story 3', 'EN', 4),('Story 4', 'EN', 3),
('Story 5', 'EN', 2),('Story 6', 'EN', 1)

// and the query
select top 3 * from (
    (select top 1 *, 1 as ranking from @stories where lang = 'DK' order by votes desc)
    union
    (select top 3 *, 2 as ranking from @stories where lang = 'EN' order by votes desc)
) x 
order by ranking, votes desc
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/982df/1).

This is of course not adapted to your specific situation, but it should give you an idea of a way that could work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method for doing what you want:

```
select top 3 s.*
from ((select top 1 s.*, 1 as inlang
       from stories s
       where s.lang = @UserLang
       order by votes desc
      ) union all
      (select s.*, 0 as inlang
       from stories s
       where s.lang = 'English'
      )
     ) s
order by inlang desc, votes desc;
```

I suspect, though, that you haven't taken into account the fact that all the highest voted stories could all be in the users language.

Answer (score 0):

Put a `Case` in your order by:

```
select top 3 * from
stories
order by case when lang = 'DK' then 1 when lang='ENG' then 2 else 3 end, votes desc
```

Sample [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/982df/9/0)

Comment: This would get three 'DK' stories and no 'ENG' if there are 3+ 'DK' stories, which isn't what the OP asked for. The result should be one 'DK' story at the top followed by 2 'EN', or 3 'EN' if there are no 'DK'.

Comment: Ahh, you are right. I misread the question. I thought we wanted to preempt with all stories from the same language if possible